# SQL Query - Return rows from table A matching any row in table B

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query which uses a list of unique LOCATIONs obtained from a first query, as criteria to query rows from a second table.

For example:

```
SELECT
 TABLE_A."LOCATION",
 MIN(TABLE_A.WORKDATE) AS MIN_WORK_DATE
FROM
 DB.TABLE_A
WHERE
 MIN_WORK_DATE > '201201'
```

Then somehow:

```
SELECT
 TABLE_B."LOCATION",
 (other fields of interest)
FROM
 DB.TABLE_B
WHERE
 TABLE_B."LOCATION" (is contained in the result above)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Use the first query as subquery along with `IN` operator

Comment: Your first query makes no sense.  You have an aggregation function `MIN()` but no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Gone - except the OP likely needs the `MIN_WORK_DATE` as well.  doing a `JOIN` on the results of the first query is likely to work better.

Comment: The first query will always return one record. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yea, my first query is in fact more complex than what I wrote as an example above, the full query includes the GROUP BY and many more WHERE conditions, as well as a two joins.

Comment: Thanks folks, the join is simplestupid, I was stuck deep in a bottomless pit of overcomplicating the answer. Back in action!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with join:

```
SELECT
 b.location,
 (other fields of interest)
FROM
 tableB b
JOIN
 (SELECT a.location, min(a.workdate) as min_workdate
   FROM tableA a   
   GROUP BY a.location) c
ON b.location = c.location
WHERE c.min_workdate > '201201'
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbaf8/1)

Comment: Thanks mareck, I can't believe i've been hung up on this for a few days where the join is so obvious! Need to take a break...

Answer (score 0):

You can match any table's column with any another table's column:

EX:

```
SELECT
 TABLE_A."LOCATION",
 TABLE_A.WORKDATE AS WORK_DATE
FROM
 DB.TABLE_A, DB.TABLE_B
WHERE
 TABLE_A.SOME_COLUMN > 'some_value_given' and TABLE_A.SOME_COLUMN=TABLE_B.SOME_COULMN
```

Comment: Hmm, looks very interesting. It won't work with my actual first query due to the complex bits i simplified, but will have to try this approach as well. Thanks!